# I was doing a functionality in Angular JS, When I search and click on button, related search data has to display using ng-click and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

```js
<script>

    var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

      $scope.srch = [{
              name: "Rani",
              phno:"145365463"
          },
          {
               name: "Raj",
              phno:"989365463"
          },
          {
               name: "Sai",
              phno:"782144635"
          },
          {
               name: "roja",
              phno:"5365463889"
          },
          {
               name: "Priya",
              phno:"321565463"
          }
        ]
</script>
```

```html
<html>

    <head>

        <title>Sample</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.js"></script> 

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div>       

  <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search for name or email" style="width:200px;"></input>

  <table class="table table-striped" ng-show="search">

    <tr ng-repeat="y in srch | filter: search">

      <td>{{y.name}}</td>      
      <td>{{y.phno}}</td>

    </tr>

  </table>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First point, `input` tag has no end tag.

Then, your AngularJS script is false. Controller code is never closed.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.srch = [{
          name: "Rani",
          phno:"145365463"
      },
      {
           name: "Raj",
          phno:"989365463"
      },
      {
           name: "Sai",
          phno:"782144635"
      },
      {
           name: "roja",
          phno:"5365463889"
      },
      {
           name: "Priya",
          phno:"321565463"
      }
    ];
}); // Don't forget to close
```

Avoid declaring `ngApp` and `ngController` on same element.

See this Plunkr working: https://plnkr.co/edit/n1lJ4uSdM5Nc7xZxM7XB?p=preview

You have to type some chars to make your list appear. What I can recommend to you is to filter your `ngRepeat` with a function instead of variable.

Comment: Thanks for sloution but When we search using char automatically list gets appears based on that but my point of question is when we click submit button only i need to search the related data

Comment: Then you have to call your function to filter and refresh the list

Comment: We already tried the same previously.Can you help us with the code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784795/applying-a-angularjs-filter-after-apply-button-click